# Routing confusions

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Check this out.

```
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Frontend', 'as' => 'frontend::'], function () {
        Route::get('', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
        Route::get('', 'FashionController@index')->name('fashion');
    });
```

I can't access the home route by route('frontend::home'). Just need to know how to access these routes. PS: I'm a newbie. A little explanation rather than hate would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part were I say home is your path(url) not the ->name

You don't need the group

```
 Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: After i edited my code as you said, it throws notfoundhttpexecption.